# solving cached css and js using localstorage

Tags: javascript

My clients often complain they can't see my upgraded css or js effect. Problem are cached files.
Maybe this could be the solution:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var a = 0;
    var b = localStorage.getItem('clear');
    if (a !== b) {
        localStorage.setItem('clear', a);           
        window.location.reload(true);
    }
});
```

Next time when I change `css` or `js` `var a` will be `1`.
Next time - `0` again, and so on.

I still didn't test this, but it's simple and should work.
Do you see any downside?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, the clean solution is to include version on url as GET parameter:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css?v=2017-12-29-01">
<script src="script.js?v=2017-12-29-01" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

It has not side effects and not needed to reload page.

**EDITED** OP post an interesting link. It seems my approach is not an universal solution. Some proxies may be configured to **don't** serve this kind of url's from cache:

#### [Revving Filenames: don’t use querystring](https://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2008/08/23/revving-filenames-dont-use-querystring/)

> The solution is to rev the name, perhaps by including the file’s timestamp or version number in the URL. But which is better: mylogo.1.2.gif or mylogo.gif?v=1.2? To gain the benefit of caching by popular proxies, avoid revving with a querystring and instead rev the filename itself.

The author concludes with:

> Proxy administrators can change the configuration to support caching resources with a querystring, when the caching headers indicate that is appropriate. But the default configuration is what web developers should expect to encounter most frequently.
>   ...
>   For those users who are behind proxies, help foster a faster experience by avoiding a querystring for cacheable resources

In this case:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style-2017-12-29-01.css">
<script src="script-2017-12-29-01.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: an interesting article about your solution - `http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2008/08/23/revving-filenames-dont-use-querystring/`

Comment: @bonaca, really interesting. I edited my answer to explain it.

Answer (score 1):

Strict equals seems to be a problem here. Change it to,

```
if (a != b) {
```

Or just convert the value retrieved from local storage to a number before doing the comparison.

```
var b = +(localStorage.getItem('clear'));
```

Comment: thanks. Does it mean that localStorage cannot store integer?

Comment: @bonaca Yeah, It would always store the values as a string.